# about background services

Tags: android, mqtt, iot

I'm developing an app for Android that should receive some notifications via a protocol similar to MQTT from an Arduino device. This notification will be a sort of   alarm and will not be continuous but it will be rare. The service will do a lite job: receive single notification, it registry in a sqlite database and sends a notification to system bar. What kind of background service I should use for API level 26 or higher. I know thet the system imposes restrictions on running background services
thanks
Luigi

Answer (score -1):

```
/*Note: IntentService is a service, and is therefore subject to the new restrictions on background services. As a result, many apps that rely on IntentService do not work properly when targeting Android 8.0 or higher. For this reason, Android Support Library 26.0.0 introduces a new JobIntentService class, which provides the same functionality as IntentService but uses jobs instead of services when running on Android 8.0 or higher.*/

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Example implementation of a JobIntentService.
 */
public class SimpleJobIntentService extends JobIntentService {
    /**
     * Unique job ID for this service.
     */
    static final int JOB_ID = 1000;

    /**
     * Convenience method for enqueuing work in to this service.
     */
    static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
        enqueueWork(context, SimpleJobIntentService.class, JOB_ID, work);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(Intent intent) {
        // We have received work to do.  The system or framework is already
        // holding a wake lock for us at this point, so we can just go.
        Log.i("SimpleJobIntentService", "Executing work: " + intent);
        String label = intent.getStringExtra("label");
        if (label == null) {
            label = intent.toString();
        }
        toast("Executing: " + label);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Log.i("SimpleJobIntentService", "Running service " + (i + 1)
                    + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        Log.i("SimpleJobIntentService", "Completed service @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        toast("All work complete");
    }

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    // Helper for showing tests
    void toast(final CharSequence text) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(SimpleJobIntentService.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question